# Is it necessary to install .NET2.0 while I have .NET3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, frameworks, .net-2.0, installation

My friend wrote an application in .NET2.0.  I'd like to install/use that application on my pc.

I have already Installed **.NET3.5 framework** on my pc.
Is it necessary for me to install **.NET2.0 framework** on my pc, too?

I am using **windowsXP**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Any application that requires .NET 2.0 will work fine with .NET 3.0 or 3.5.**

Versions 3.0 and 3.5 of the .NET Framework both use version 2.0 of the CLR, the exact same version as .NET 2.0. This means that they are both [in-place updates](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/net-framework-35.aspx). Only new features were added.

See this handy diagram for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have .Net 3.5 you already have .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should probably install the 2.0 version of .Net too.

While .Net 3.5 is designed to be backwards compatible, there are strange corner cases where the behaviour is different between the two. Your best bet is to install both.

Comment: Those corner cases are certainly present between .NET 1.1 and later versions, and .NET 4.0 and earlier versions. But I'm not aware of any for 2.0–3.5. Do you have any examples or personal experience of this?

Comment: I have experienced them, but don't have examples that I can share. As you progress through service packs, the behaviour sometimes changes, too. As far as I know this is restricted to pre Vista OSes.